# How to hide checkbox for specific records or only to parent rows in lightning treegrid

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I would like to hide the checkbox only for parent rows . I am not sure how to achieve it. I went through the lightning library but I couldn't find any information related to it.

```
<lightning:treeGrid aura:id="Tree" 
                            columns="{!v.gridColumns}" 
                            data="{!v.gridData}" 
                            expandedRows="{!v.gridExpandedRows}"
                            hideCheckboxColumn = "true" />
```

Is there any way where I can pass the boolean value dynamically to `hideCheckboxColumn` in the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO. you cannot the attribute `hideCheckboxColumn` is at the component level and its `all or nothing` kind to show/hide checkboxes.

you will have to most likely create your own component using the markup and CSS provided in lightning design system

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: I had similar requirement and indeed there is no property for that. But since I didn't want to create my own tree component, I just user the rowselected event and if the user select row that he shouldn't I remove it from the selection. It's not so user friendly but enough for me